# HTML nested lists in Wordpress

Tags: html, wordpress, nested-lists

I'm trying to do nested, ordered lists using `ol` types and though the code looks right in the Wordpress preview, it doesn't show correctly when I preview in Firefox and IE, the lists all show as numbered lists instead of the types I specified in the code. My code is below. Can someone help me find what's wrong?

Thanks in advance for any help!
Kelly

```
Teaching your kids about money isn't always child's play. But helping them make smart choices early will pay off later.
<span style="text-decoration: underline;">Baby Steps</span>
<h4>Even the cartoon set can learn the value of a dollar. Some simple ideas:</h4>
<ol class="alt1">
    <li>Show your toddler the various coins in your pocket or change purse and see if the clever tyke knows what each one can buy.
<ol type="a">
    <li>Gum machines or mechanical rides still take coins. Or try old-fashioned "penny candy" shops, even if that bubble gum goes for a dime now.</li>
    <li>How many coins are necessary to buy a popsicle or frozen yogurt at the ice cream truck?</li>
    <li>Field trip: checking the prices at the grocery store can be instructive for kids —and their parents, too!</li>
</ol>
<ol class="alt2">
<ol type="i">
    <li>Where does money come from (besides the ATM machine)? Discuss getting paid for work and how your salary lets you buy things for the family.</li>
    <li>Lemonade stands still do a thriving business for first-time entrepreneurs.</li>
    <li>Old toys can be contributed to Mom’s and Dad's yard sale to score a profit.</li>
    <li>Discuss the best way to invest the proceeds with your tiny mogul. Hint: don't blow it all on candy or games.</li>
</ol>
</ol>
Older kids can understand the difference between necessary and optional purchases. Milk or gummi bears?
<h2>Here's Your Allowance</h2>
<h4>Yep, it's still a great teaching tool after all these years. Some ways to get with the program:</h4>
<ol class="alt1">
    <li>Doling out the cash on a weekly basis makes sense. Even older kids may find it tough to budget a month in advance.</li>
    <li>Decide whether there will be strings tied to the stipend. Will Junior have to complete household chores before you fork over the cash?</li>
</ol>
<ol class="alt1">
<ol type="a">
    <li>Some families think helping around the house should be expected and unrelated to the weekly payout.</li>
    <li>Other parents think it's a good way to introduce the idea of working for money and getting paid for a job well done.</li>
</ol>
</ol>
<ol>
    <li value="3">In coming up with a dollar amount, savvy parents will not fall for reports of what the other parents are shelling out. Multiplying your own allowance in the distant past by the rate of inflation may be a good starting point.</li>
</ol>
</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 1):

To nest one list inside another, you have to place it inside a <li> element. You can't put it directly inside an <ol> element.

In other words, replace this:

```
<ol>
<ol>
...
</ol>
</ol>
```

with this:

```
<ol>
<li>
<ol>
...
</ol>
</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested both a non wordpress html page and wordpress entry.  My guess is wordpess is stripping your type tag so try using CSS. Give each < li > a class and for your css use [list-style-type](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_list-style-type.asp) to declare the list-item marker type.

ie:
ol.lower-alpha {list-style-type:lower-alpha}
li.lower-latin {list-style-type:lower-latin}